# making poisson spheres distribution on python but cannot figure out where is the bug

Tags: python, poisson, povray

I am new to programming, so I hope my stupid questions do not bug you.
I am now trying to calculate the poisson sphere distribution(a 3D version of the poisson disk) using python and then plug in the result to POV-RAY so that I can generate some random distributed packing rocks.
I am following these two links:
[https://github.com/CodingTrain/Rainbow-Code/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_33_poisson_disc/sketch.js#L13]
[https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf]
tl;dr 
0.Create an n-dimensional grid array and cell size = r/sqrt(n) where r is the minimum distance between each sphere. All arrays are set to be default -1 which stands for 'without point'
1.Create an initial sample. (it should be placed randomly but I choose to put it in the middle). Put it in the grid array. Also, intialize an active array. Put the initial sample in the active array.
2.While the active list is not empty, pick a random index. Generate points near it and make sure the points are not overlapping with nearby points(only test with the nearby arrays). If no sample can be created near the 'random index', kick the 'random index' out. Loop the process.

And here is my code:

```
import math
from random import uniform
import numpy
import random
radius = 1      #you can change the size of each sphere
mindis = 2 * radius
maxx = 10         #you can change the size of the container
maxy = 10
maxz = 10
k = 30
cellsize = mindis / math.sqrt(3)
nrofx = math.floor(maxx / cellsize)
nrofy = math.floor(maxy / cellsize)
nrofz = math.floor(maxz / cellsize)
grid = []
active = []
default = numpy.array((-1, -1, -1))
for fillindex in range(nrofx * nrofy * nrofz):
    grid.append(default)
x = uniform(0, maxx)
y = uniform(0, maxy)
z = uniform(0, maxz)
firstpos = numpy.array((x, y,  z))
firsti = maxx // 2
firstj = maxy // 2
firstk = maxz // 2
grid[firsti + nrofx * (firstj + nrofy * firstk)] = firstpos
active.append(firstpos)
while (len(active) > 0) :
    randindex = math.floor(uniform(0,len(active)))
    pos = active[randindex]
    found = False
    for attempt in range(k):
        offsetx = uniform(mindis, 2 * mindis)
        offsety = uniform(mindis, 2 * mindis)
        offsetz = uniform(mindis, 2 * mindis)
        samplex = offsetx * random.choice([1,-1])
        sampley = offsety * random.choice([1,-1])
        samplez = offsetz * random.choice([1,-1])
        sample = numpy.array((samplex, sampley, samplez))
        sample = numpy.add(sample, pos)
        xcoor = math.floor(sample.item(0) / cellsize)
        ycoor = math.floor(sample.item(1) / cellsize)
        zcoor = math.floor(sample.item(2) / cellsize)
        attemptindex = xcoor + nrofx * (ycoor + nrofy * zcoor)
        if attemptindex >= 0 and attemptindex < nrofx * nrofy * nrofz and     numpy.all([sample, default]) == True and xcoor > 0 and ycoor > 0 and zcoor > 0 :
            test = True
            for testx in range(-1,2):
                for testy in range(-1, 2):
                    for testz in range(-1, 2):
                        testindex = (xcoor + testx) + nrofx * ((ycoor + testy) + nrofy * (zcoor + testz))
                        if testindex >=0 and testindex < nrofx * nrofy * nrofz :
                            neighbour = grid[testindex]
                            if numpy.all([neighbour, sample]) == False:
                                if numpy.all([neighbour, default]) == False:
                                    distance = numpy.linalg.norm(sample - neighbour)
                                    if distance > mindis:
                                        test = False
            if test == True and len(active)<len(grid):
                found = True
                grid[attemptindex] = sample
                active.append(sample)
    if found == False:
        del active[randindex]

for printout in range(len(grid)):
    print("<" + str(active[printout][0]) + "," + str(active[printout][1]) + "," + str(active[printout][2]) + ">")
print(len(grid))
```

My code seems to run forever.
Therefore I tried to add a print(len(active)) in the last of the while loop. 
Surprisingly, I think I discovered the bug as the length of the active list just keep increasing! (It is supposed to be the same length as the grid) I think the problem is caused by the active.append(), but I can't figure out where is the problem as the code is literally the 90% the same as the one made by Mr.Shiffman.
I don't want to free ride this but I have already checked again and again while correcting again and again for this code :(. Still, I don't know where the bug is. (why do the active[] keep appending!?)
Thank you for the precious time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  The links are missing, and you should include information that is critical to the question in the body of the question, not in links.  Also, no need to apologize, we're all here to learn.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Pretty much any IDE will let you step through the code and identify the value of each variable at each step, which is what you need to do to debug your program.  Don't assume that the code you found somewhere on the internet is correct.

Comment: Hi, I am not 100% sure about what IDE means but I think it means the place I run the code? If yes, I am using PyCharm with Project Interpreter Python 3.6.1. The links are 
[https://github.com/CodingTrain/Rainbow-Code/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_33_poisson_disc/sketch.js#L1
and
[https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf
The code creator ran the code in this video:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flQgnCUxHlw
so I think it should be my problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comments by the way :).